# In how many ways can a committee consisting of $1$ president, $1$ vice-president and three members from a poll of $12$ people be selected?

Tags: combinatorics

We have to form a committee consists of $1$ president, $1$ vice-president and $3$ members from a poll of $12$ people. How many ways can we do it?

Is not this simply a selecting $5$ people from $12$ $$\frac{12!}{5!7!}$$ type of problem?

If not, then can you please explain why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. After having chosen $5$ people, you still have to decide which one of them will be president and wich one will be vice-president. Therefore, you'all have to multiply your answer, which is $\binom{12}5$, by $20(=5\times4)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to account here for the permutation of the people among themselves. Let's say you selected A(president) and B, C, D and E as the other 4 members. Now there might be another case where B is president and A, C, D, and E are the other 4 members. That is although we are selecting the same group of people, their way of organization matters here.

So the answer here would be $\frac{12!}{5!7!}*\frac{5!}{3!}$.